# Why does induction over finite sets require finiteness?

Tags: induction, set-theory

This question comes from a theorem stated in Suppes' Axiomatic Set Theory page 102 when the author introduces induction over finite sets. The theorem states: If

1. $A$ is finite,
2. $\varphi(\varnothing)$
3. $\forall x \forall B (x \in A \land B \subseteq A \land \varphi(B) \implies \varphi(B\cup \{x\}))$

Then $\varphi(A)$.

My question is: why would we require $A$ to be finite? Does the theorem fail otherwise? Consider this intuitive formulation of premise #3: Given a subset $B$ of $A$ that has only even numbers, whenever we expand $B$ with **any** element of $A$, we obtain another set of even numbers. From this formulation, it seems obvious that $A$ itself must be a set of even numbers, no matter whether it is finite or infinite. But then, why would we require as a premise that $A$ be finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \Bbb{N}$, the set of all natural numbers and let $\phi(X)$ be true iff $X$ is a finite set. Then $2$ and $3$ both hold:

2. $\emptyset$ is finite
3. if $B$ is a finite set of natural numbers and $x$ is natural number, then $B \cup \{x\}$ is finite.

But $A = \Bbb{N}$ is not finite. I.e., $\phi(A)$ does not hold.

I find it more natural to formalise this induction principle without involving $A$:

> $\phi(X)$ holds for all finite $X$ if:
>
> (i) $\phi(\emptyset)$, and:
>
> (ii) whenever $B$ is finite and $\phi(B)$ then also $\phi(B \cup \{x\})$.

Suppes' version follows by restricting $\phi$, $B$, $x$ and $X$ to some given finite $A$.

Comment: Thank you, this made it very clear!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean: why do we require $A$ to be finite?

Let's suppose that $A$ is a set. Suppose now that for any unary predicate $\phi(-)$, if (2) and (3) hold then $\phi(A)$ holds.

Now take $\phi(X)$ to be the statement "$X$ is finite".

Note that $\phi(\emptyset)$ holds, since the empty set is clearly finite.

And note that for any $B, x$, if $\phi(B)$ holds, then $B$ is finite and therefore so is $B \cup \{x\}$.

Therefore, $A$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it was just as useful as the accepted one!